# Running a Java application from my desktop generates a "Could not find main class" error

Tags: java, eclipse

I currently use Eclipse to maintain my java application. I can run the application from Eclipse without any problems. I can also run the Ant build successfully. However, after I install the java application on my desktop, I receive the "Java Virtual Machine Launcher: Could not find main class..." error. What could cause this error at run time? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you click the dropdown arrow next to the run button, select "run configurations...", and post a screenshot of what the first tab shows?

Answer (score 0):

open your application.jar location in console and try

```
    java -jar <yourAppname.jar>
```

Remember that on eclipse you have to use export->runnable jar option to produce application jar